# Error Returning Address of Variable

Tags: c, return-value

We're supposed to write a function that will return the address of the first occurrence of ch in string str. I wrote the below code, which runs and seems to return numbers that could be correct (I called the function 5 times for the 5 characters in a string and the return values were separated by 1 byte.) However, the ampersand in the return statement is underlined in red with the hover-over text, "Return value type does not match the function type." I don't understand how the code builds and runs if there is an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int mystrchr (char *str, char ch){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        if(str[i]==ch)
        {
            //printf("%c\n",str[i]);
            return &str[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know `&str[i];` is not of type `int`?

Comment: " I don't understand how the code builds and runs if there is an error." - use the compiler switch `-Werror` (or whatever your compiler's version of that is) to prevent the building and running.  Some compiler vendors apparently think it is useful to produce a rubbish executable for bad code, in the default mode

Comment: change the return type from int to char*

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the reason:
From you defined funtion `int mystrchr (char *str, char ch){}`, the return type is `int`, but the real value is `&str[i];`, the type is `char *` in your code.

so there is a warning..

Answer (score 0):

```
char* mystrchr (char *str, char ch){
int i;
for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
    if(str[i]==ch)
    {
        break;
    }
}
return &str[i];
}
```

I agree with others.